# Reading the content of a VISIO file from top to bottom in a sequence using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, visio

I am trying to write the Name of the Shapes and the corresponding text in an excel sheet,That is from top to bottom. The program that I have written reads the data randomly anywhere covering all the blocks.

I want my program to read the file from top to bottom in a sequence according to the flow of the graph.

This is the program in which I am working with

```
pages = application.ActiveDocument.Pages
i=1
for page in pages:
    print('SheetName:' + str(page))
    i=i+1
    sheet1.write(i,0,('SheetName:' + str(page)))
    for shape in page.Shapes:
        print (shape.Name + " '" + shape.Text)
        sheet1.write(i,1,shape.Name)
        sheet1.write(i,2,shape.Text)
        i=i+1
wb.save('example1.xls')'
```

Can you please help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no method in Visio like `page.GetShapesAccordingToTheGraph`, you'll need to do it yourself.. As a first step, you can find all shape interconnections (build the "graph"), and as a second step, traverse that graph in the sequence that makes sense for you.

1. Building the graph. You can use Visio `shape.ConnectedShapes` or `Connects` to find the connected shapes. You can refer this great article for getting started with finding connections: https://blog.bvisual.net/2016/08/09/understanding-visio-connections/
2. Traversing. The easiest method is to use Bread First Search, or Depth First Search for example.. it all depends on how your shapes are connected (are there loops/cycles, for example, and how do you want to process alternate paths).

In trivial case when there are no loops and no alternate paths, (2) would be effectively just iteration of the shapes according to their (single) outgoing connection.
First you find shape without incoming edges, then, starting from that shape, get the one that is connected to it using outgoing edge, then repeat for that connected shape, until there are no more.